# Apache multiple VirtualHost .conf files

Tags: apache2

There's something basic I must be misunderstanding about Apache's VirtualHost format and .conf files. What I want to do is run N > 1 independent sites on a single host, with each site entirely wrapped up into a Docker container (classic microservice architecture). On the host itself (which is running Apache), I want to create a simple landing page with links to all of these different sites (i.e. http://localhost/ goes to the landing page, http://localhost/site1 goes to one site, http://localhost/site2 goes to another site, etc.

The first site (RocketChat, being served by Docker on host port 8081) has the following text in rocketchat.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyRequests off
    ServerName localhost
    ProxyPass /chat http://localhost:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse /chat http://localhost:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

I placed this file in etc/apache2/sites-available/, ran a2ensite, and reloaded apache. Everything works perfectly, where http://localhost gives me the default Apache site and http://localhost/chat gives me RocketChat.

I tried to deploy the second site, Xowa, in the exact same way (Docker service on host port 8082). Here's xowa.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyRequests off
    ServerName localhost
    ProxyPass /xowa http://localhost:8082/
    ProxyPassReverse /xowa http://localhost:8082/
</VirtualHost>
```

I enabled the site and reloaded Apache, but unfortunately this doesn't work. I can access Xowa just fine if I type http://localhost:8082, but http://localhost/xowa just returns a 404. Even stranger, if I disable the rocketchat.conf site on Apache (i.e. I do a2dissite rocketchat.conf) then the Xowa site works fine.

I don't quite know how to interpret this: does Apache think that the rocketchat.conf VirtualHost should handle the request, and then it drops it because it doesn't match the correct ProxyPass? I thought Apache would just "go down the list" until it finds a match. Any advice/explanations here would be much much appreciated, I'm relatively new to Apache configuration and excited to learn. Thanks!

Comment: The contents of ``VirtualHost`` for same ``ServerName`` and port are not merged. Put the entries in one ``VirtualHost``.